# d3.js static graph scrolling

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to implement the following example

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4566102

For large graphs, I just want the graph to not get cut-off and allow scrolling, once user drags it outside the current border.

I tried adding the overflow:scroll property to the svg element, but that doesn't seem to work. 
I am new at this javascript/d3.js programming and would be glad if someone can point out the error or just guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this example of panning the kind of thing you're looking for? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919

Comment: @RichardMarr Thanks. That is actually what I want to do but in the static graph. I don't see a drag behaviour defined in the example. Does the zoom function handle it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about making the svg large enough, but wrapping it into a smalle div with overflow: auto?

html

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <svg></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.inner {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
svg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fgeNp/)

You can drag the red circle out of the visible area.

Comment: What if the graph is HUGE, and I don't want to load / display all data once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this will not be possible without javascript intervention. The `svg` root element must have a defined width and height, and it won't adapt at any extent to its contents.

If you are going for google, your question is more about `svg` than about `d3`.

I think the only possibility is to use javascript, in order to increase the sizes of `svg` when one object goes behind it. In this way, though, i can't figure out how to make it work for the left side, it becomes complicated.

I think it's better to tackle the problem with the solutions that d3 can offer you, like the zoom behaviour suggested above. And generally if you are new in this field i can suggest you to think the interaction *before* going for the implementation, picking examples from the d3 gallery in order to better understand what you really want.